# Multiply python dictionary keys by a constant

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to define a function `def times_ten(start: int, end:int)` that will multiply each key by 10 and return a dictionary with those values.
Example:
`d = times_ten(3,6)`
`print(d)`
returns
`{3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60}`.

Comment: What did you try and why does a start value of `1` and an an end value of `3` lead to the keys `3`, `4`, `5` and `6`?

Comment: How do you provide the keys 3, 4, 5, 6 to this function?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally typed 1 and 3 when they should've been 3 and 6

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def times_ten(start, end):
    return {n: n * 10 for n in range(start, end)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dict comprehension

```
def times_ten(start, stop):
    return {i: i*10 for i in range(start, stop)

>>> times_ten(3, 6)
{3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50}
```

Note that is is canonical for most ranges in python to be half-open, in other words the *include* the start value but *exclude* the end value, `[start, stop)`.